# How can I display only a specific year from the date in qlik?

Tags: sql, date, format, qlikview, qliksense

I have a question about a column called OrderDate. The column has the format: SET TimestampFormat='M/D/YYY h:mm:ss[.fff] TT';

I am very new to Qlik, so I don't know where to set the year = 2008. I tried several options in SQL but it didn't work well.

I need the year 2008 to compare the total revenue of 2008 with 2009. How is this possible?

In the image I have the function Year(OrderDate) as row value, but for the comparison I want the year as column.

[image]

The Mockup of the Table would be like this:
[image]

Comment: You want to remove the `Year` column and add another column that compare 2008 and 2009 sales?

Comment: No I just want the Year filtert once in 2008 and once in 2009 so that I can compare the sales amount of these two years. The Dateformat of OrderDate (Colum) is 'M/D/YYY h:mm:ss[.fff] TT'. And I do not know how I can get just the Year. In SQL it probably would: SELECT Sales, Extract(Year from OrderDate) FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate='2008'

Comment: This is the Table of SalesOrders in Qlik:
LOAD
    SalesOrderID,
    OrderDate,
    Status,
    SalesOrderNumber,
    CustomerID,
    TaxAmt,
    Freight,
    LocalCurrency
FROM [lib://Demo:DataFiles/Demotabellen_SalesOrderHeader.qvd](qvd);
Have I add sth. over here, or make a new measure where Year = '2008'?

Comment: In the Qlik Dataeditor I did this so far: LOAD
    SalesOrderID,
    Year(OrderDate) as LY
 FROM [lib://Demo:DataFiles/Demotabellen_SalesOrderHeader.qvd]
(qvd)
where OrderDate = '2008';

So maybe I have to create an measure with sth. like this: Sum({<{Year} = {"$(LY)"}>}(ListPrice *OrderQty)/100)

Comment: you can always have the year extracted in a new field during the reload using the [date](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2021/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/FormattingFunctions/Date.htm) and [date#](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2021/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/InterpretationFunctions/date_hash.htm)

Comment: It depends in what format is the `OrderDate` (inside the qvd) but the script can be something like this:
```
Load
 *
Where
 OrderYear = '2008'
;
LOAD 
  SalesOrderID, 
  OrderDate, 
  Year(OrderDate) as OrderYar,
  Status, 
  SalesOrderNumber, 
  CustomerID, 
  TaxAmt, 
  Freight, 
  LocalCurrency 
FROM [lib://Demo:DataFiles/Demotabellen_SalesOrderHeader.qvd](qvd);
```

Comment: But this will filter the whole dataset to show only data for year = 2008 (which im assuming is not ideal). Possible to show a mock-up of what table is expected as result?

Comment: I have added the mockup to the desired table above. 
There is also the option to recognize with Year like: in the column name, but the sales are always shown only from all years (like in Total sales)